# How do I retrieve multiple values ​from firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

One is possible with .whereEqualTo("name","a").

For example
'where name= "a" or name="b"'
How do you put the conditions?

Comment: I solved it with   '.where in()'

Comment: What programming language/platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`in`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any). From that link:

> ```
> citiesRef.where('country', 'in', ['USA', 'Japan']);
> ```

Comment: When I use the command where, I get the following error.

Cannot resolve method 'where' in 'collection_name'

Comment: The exact syntax depends on the language, which you didn't specify in the question. If you click the link I included, it shows most of the supported languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can also chain multiple methods to create more specific queries (logical AND).

```
citiesRef.whereEqualTo("state", "CO").whereEqualTo("name", "Denver");
```

You can read more about that in the **Compound queries** documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).

Comment: Is it possible to search multiple in one column?

Comment: Sure, you can use the `whereIn(fieldPath, listOfValues)` method.
Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#public-query-wherein-fieldpath-fieldpath,-list-extends-object-values

Comment: If you do two `where` calls it performs and AND, not an OR.